# Jquery - Detect div from #hash tag and display selected menu li

Tags: jquery, list, menuitem, selected

First of all my english isn't that good - but i'll try making myself understandable.

I'm making a website with a jQuery parallax scroll effect (something like the nikebetterworld.com site) - And it's getting better and better. But now in the process i have found something that would add some value to the navigation.

The navigation is placed in the left side of the screen - and my question is:
How can i make a menu (ul li a) which will display the selected menu-list item when clicked AND if you scroll down the site how can I make it display the part of the site which it relates to via the #hash tag.

I hope that my question is understandable?

Right now its looking something like this:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#intro" title="Next Section"><img src="images/dot.png" alt="Link" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#second" title="Next Section"><img src="images/dot.png" alt="Link" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#third" title="Next Section"><img src="images/dot.png" alt="Link" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#fifth" title="Next Section"><img src="images/dot.png" alt="Link" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

So what i want is getting jQuery to display which part of the page the user is 'on' by highlighting one of the list items.

Can you guys help me :) ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a jQuery module called [ScrollSpy](https://github.com/sxalexander/jquery-scrollspy) that does this - you can see it in action in [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy).

Comment: Its exactly what I'm looking for! But I'm having trouble getting it to work. It seems complicated. Can you help me out ? - Im confused about how to do it? I have downloaded scrollspy js - and added a link to the js document but I'm confused about what to add to the html doc ?

Comment: It's all in the /demo folder of the download